# How to get the "Function Url" which is with in a Function-App deployed using Terraform?

Tags: azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, infrastructure-as-code

As part of IaC, A **Function App**, lets name it *FuncAppX* is deployed using Terraform, which has a function with-in.

I need to access the *Url* of the same function with-in a function app using Terraform. I am sharing the screenshot for same here for reference, in which its easy to get the "*GetFunction Url*" but using terraform, I am not getting a way to return the same, which needed to be passed as an input to another function app.

[Function App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEidN.jpg)
[Function within FunctionApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHTFt.jpg)

Comment: Dont link to external image services. Add them to this post so the question will still be understandable in the future.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to build the URL of a specific function endpoint yourself. Since the concrete function names are defined via the `function.json`, you need to copy it to your Terraform scripts.

```
locals {
  function_foo = "foo"
}
```

The URL contains a secret as query parameter, which you can grab via the data source `azurerm_function_app_host_keys`.

```
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "example" {
  name                = azurerm_function_app.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_function_app.example.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [azurerm_function_app.example]
}
```

Now you can build the URL yourself.

```
output "url" {
  value = "https://${azurerm_function_app.example.default_hostname}/api/${local.function_foo}?code=${data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.example.default_function_key}"
}
```

Be aware, that the `azurerm_function_app_host_keys` values may not immediately available, since the deployment of the concrete Function App is decoupled from the `azurerm_function_app` service creation. Depending on your scenario, you may need to add some manual synchronization (e.g. with `null_resource`).

Comment: Function App Host Key != Function Key

Answer (score 3):

Concider exposing you http triggered functions via the **API management** resource in azure. However you can call functions directly also.

To get the url of the function app you can use the **default_hostname** attribute on **azurerm_function_app** and forexample put in a keyvault using **azurerm_key_vault_secret**.

The attribute is listed in the terraform documentation [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app#default_hostname).

Of course this will not link to the specific function and will not include the key needed.

To extract a key needed to access the function you can use the [function_app_host_keys](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/function_app_host_keys). Where you get the default function key with

Then you can retrieve the **default_function_key**.

Then you need to combine these things to call the function (note you can only call functions with a http trigger).

The url of the function would then be **{default_hostname}/api/{functionname}?code={default_function_key}**.