# Azure Function Url doesn't include authentication code when using azurerm_runction_app_function in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

When you setup a Function in Azure, it lets you get the default function Url with the function key. It looks sort of like:

[https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/my-function-name?code=[authentication-code]](https://my-function-app.azurewebsites.net/api/my-function-name?code=%5Bauthentication-code%5D)

This lets me call that function from an API endpoint without using any other authentication. I am trying to get access to that key via the azurerm provider somehow.   UPDATE:  I am using version 1.1.7 of Terraform and v3.0.2 of azurerm provider.

I can get the main Url (not including the authentication code) using azurerm_function_app_function.my-function.url. I can get the host key using data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.default_function_key.

```
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "function-host-keys" {
  name                = azurerm_windows_function_app.function-app.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.resource-group.name
}

resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "my-function" {
  name            = my-function
  function_app_id = azurerm_windows_function_app.function-app.id
  language        = "CSharp"

  file {
    name    = "MyFunc.cs"
    content = file("../../MyFunc.cs")
  }

  config_json = jsonencode({
    "bindings" = [
      {
        "authLevel" = "function"
        "direction" = "in"
        "methods" = [
          "get",
          "post",
        ]
        "name" = "req"
        "type" = "httpTrigger"
      },
      {
        "direction" = "out"
        "name"      = "$return"
        "type"      = "http"
      }
    ]
  })
}

locals {
  # This gets the host key but I need the function key
  host-key = data.azurerm_function_app_host_keys.function-host-keys.default_function_key

  # This gets the url, but without the "?code=######" 
  url = azurerm_function_app_function.my-function.url

  # How do I get the function key for the ?code=#### part of the Url?
  code = data.azurerm_some_function_resource.function_key
}
```

But I can’t seem to find anything that gives me the default function key for my specific function, as is available in the Azure portal. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by `function_key`? I would take `default_function_key` of `azurerm_function_app_host_keys`, see [How to get the "Function Url"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264252/846163). What is the difference?

Comment: I don't know how better to describe the `function_key`.  That is what it is called in the Azure Portal.  If you'll note in my description, I already said that `azurerm_function_app_host_keys.default_function_key` gives you the `host key` as it is called in the Portal.  The key I am after is specific to the function itself, not the function app, which is what the host key is.  If you get the function URL, there are several options under the dropdown.  One option is the URL with the "default function key".  That is function specific and is what I am trying to get from the azurerm provider.

Comment: I cannot confirm your experience with the `host key`. When setting up an `HttpTrigger` function, `default_function_key` the returns the function key from the Azure Portal. But I haven't used `config_json` so far. Maybe it causes the issue?

Comment: Interestingly, I had the same problem last week once, while playing with newer versions of Terraform and azurerm provider. But I couldn't reproduce it afterwards. Which version do you use, Matt?

Comment: Ooops...I forgot to include that.  It's version 1.1.7 of terraform and v3.0.2 of azurerm.  I'll update to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use a data source with a depends_on for the newly created FunctionApp?

```
data "azurerm_function_app_host_keys" "item" {
  name                = azurerm_function_app.item.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_function_app.item.resource_group_name

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_function_app.item
  ]
}
```

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/8515#issuecomment-694515657

Comment: I think maybe my question is not clear.  I'll try to update it to make it clearer.  I haven't had any trouble with the `azurerm_function_app_host_keys` resource getting created or anything.  The only problem is that it doesn't give me the information I need.  It provides the host key (as is implied by the name) but not the authentication code that I need for the function itself.  My impression is that `azurerm` does not support this right now, but I wanted to ask in case I was missing something.